# How to sort when we use aggregate function?

Tags: opportunity, map, list, aggregate, order

I have a formula field that orders a particular field values. Example: A field for employees profession, for each profession there is an equivalent number value like, "IT = 1, Doctor = 2". I'm using this to sort the objects records by Profession Order.

Here is the code we are using:

```
Map<Id,Map<Id,decimal>> personTotalHoursMap = new Map<Id,Map<Id,decimal>>();
    List<AggregateResult> timeSheetsAggResult
    = [SELECT SUM(Hours__c) TotalHours, Person_Object__c, Opportunity__c
        FROM Time_Sheets__c
        GROUP BY Opportunity__c, Person_Object__c];
    for(AggregateResult personAggResult : timeSheetsAggResult)
    {
        Id oppId = (Id)personAggResult .get('Opportunity__c');
        Id pOId= (Id)personAggResult .get('Person_Object__c');
        decimal totalHours = 0;
        if(personAggResult.get('Hours') != null)
            totalHours = (decimal)personAggResult.get('TotalHours');

        //Omitted some codes...

    }
```

I want to sort this using the `Person_Object__r.Profession_Order__c`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY Clause can be used to sort by field. But the same field needs to be aggregated as well. Like below:

```
    [SELECT SUM(Hours__c) TotalHours, Person_Object__c, Opportunity__c, Person_Object__r.Profession_Order__c
            FROM Time_Sheets__c
                 GROUP BY Opportunity__c, Person_Object__c, Person_Object__r.Profession_Order__c 
                          ORDER BY Person_Object__r.Profession_Order__c ASC]
```

Comment: I tried this but there was an error when I loaded the page: `System.UnexpectedException: field 'Profession_Order__c' can not be grouped in a query call`

Comment: whats the data type of Profession_Order__c?

Comment: it is a formula field and we are using `CASE` function to return what number is the string for profession.

Comment: thats the problem .Formula field cannot be used in GROUP BY ....

Comment: How many options do you have in Profession_Order__c? if the number of options is less, you can use a map and a for loop. The query needs to be outside the for loop so you dont hit SOQL limits.

Comment: @Shruthi, at least I have 10.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are using formula field in GROUPBY clause which causes the error .

Create a workflow to populate the same result on your record and use that field in aggregation instead .